# Python ljust(): difference in console and Browser

Tags: python, html, django-templates

```
kt = 'B'
urk = '1234567'
code = kt+urk.ljust(15)+'me'
```

In pycharm console code seems:

```
B1234567        me
```

But with printing code in django template as `{{ code }}` seems like `B1234567 me` .
How can I modify 'code' for seems like console.

Thanks in advance

Comment: use `<pre>{{ code }}</pre>` for pre-formatted text.

Comment: @TheNone - Please either write an answer yourself and accept it, either delete the question... don't leave unanswered questions hanging around SO! :)

Comment: @Dan, Please write your comment as answer for accept. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<pre>{{ code }}</pre>` for pre-formatted text.

Comment: A small explanation how this fix helps, will not hurt.